Pintools - Failure to open DLL file WS2_32.dll
I'm writing a pintools using Pin. My pintool needs to implement some socket functionalities, so I included the winsock2 lib. When compiling the pintool with the Pin makefile I got the following error:
E: [tid:9032] Failure to open DLL file WS2_32.dll
E:       System error 2 : Failure to initialize DLL C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Università\Magistrale\Cyberoo\PinTools\pin\source\tools\ManualExamples\obj-intel64\branch_logger.dll
E:       See preceding message to find out the reason

The makefile is simple:
ifdef PIN_ROOT
CONFIG_ROOT := $(PIN_ROOT)/source/tools/Config
else
CONFIG_ROOT := ../Config
endif
include $(CONFIG_ROOT)/makefile.config
include makefile.rules
include $(TOOLS_ROOT)/Config/makefile.default.rules

makefile.rules:
#
# Copyright (C) 2012-2023 Intel Corporation.
# SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
#

##############################################################
#
# This file includes all the test targets as well as all the
# non-default build rules and test recipes.
#
##############################################################


##############################################################
#
# Test targets
#
##############################################################

###### Place all generic definitions here ######

# This defines tests which run tools of the same name.  This is simply for convenience to avoid
# defining the test name twice (once in TOOL_ROOTS and again in TEST_ROOTS).
# Tests defined here should not be defined in TOOL_ROOTS and TEST_ROOTS.
TEST_TOOL_ROOTS := inscount0 inscount1 inscount2 proccount imageload staticcount detach malloctrace \
                   malloc_mt inscount_tls stack-debugger pinatrace itrace isampling safecopy invocation countreps \
                   nonstatica

# This defines the tests to be run that were not already defined in TEST_TOOL_ROOTS.
TEST_ROOTS :=

# This defines the tools which will be run during the the tests, and were not already defined in
# TEST_TOOL_ROOTS.
TOOL_ROOTS :=

# This defines the static analysis tools which will be run during the the tests. They should not
# be defined in TEST_TOOL_ROOTS. If a test with the same name exists, it should be defined in
# TEST_ROOTS.
# Note: Static analysis tools are in fact executables linked with the Pin Static Analysis Library.
# This library provides a subset of the Pin APIs which allows the tool to perform static analysis
# of an application or dll. Pin itself is not used when this tool runs.
SA_TOOL_ROOTS :=

# This defines all the applications that will be run during the tests.
APP_ROOTS := fibonacci little_malloc

# This defines any additional object files that need to be compiled.
OBJECT_ROOTS :=

# This defines any additional dlls (shared objects), other than the pintools, that need to be compiled.
DLL_ROOTS :=

# This defines any static libraries (archives), that need to be built.
LIB_ROOTS :=

###### Place OS-specific definitions here ######

# Linux
ifeq ($(TARGET_OS),linux)
    TEST_TOOL_ROOTS += buffer_linux fork_jit_tool follow_child_tool strace emudiv replacesigprobed
    TEST_ROOTS += statica
    SA_TOOL_ROOTS += statica
    APP_ROOTS += fork_app follow_child_app1 follow_child_app2 divide_by_zero
endif

# macOS*
ifeq ($(TARGET_OS),mac)
    TEST_TOOL_ROOTS += fork_jit_tool follow_child_tool strace
    TEST_ROOTS += statica prefer_parse_image_from_file
    SA_TOOL_ROOTS += statica
    APP_ROOTS += fork_app follow_child_app1 follow_child_app2
endif

# Windows
ifeq ($(TARGET_OS),windows)
    TEST_TOOL_ROOTS += w_malloctrace buffer_windows emudiv replacesigprobed dumpargv
    APP_ROOTS += divide_by_zero
    LDFLAGS += -lws2_32
endif

###### Handle exceptions here (OS/arch related) ######

RUNNABLE_TESTS := $(TEST_TOOL_ROOTS) $(TEST_ROOTS)

###### Handle exceptions here (bugs related) ######

# TODO: These tests fail - fix and remove the following:

# See Mantis 4311 for nonstatica
ifeq ($(TARGET_OS),windows)
    TEST_TOOL_ROOTS := $(filter-out nonstatica, $(TEST_TOOL_ROOTS))
endif

ifeq ($(TARGET_OS),mac)
    MACOS_VERSION_GE_1100 := $(shell $(TOOLS_ROOT)/Utils/testMacOsVersion ge 11.0.0)
    ifeq ($(MACOS_VERSION_GE_1100), 1)
        # See mantis 4883
        TEST_TOOL_ROOTS := $(filter-out follow_child_tool, $(TEST_TOOL_ROOTS))
    endif
endif

###### Define the sanity subset ######

# This defines the list of tests that should run in sanity. It should include all the tests listed in
# TEST_TOOL_ROOTS and TEST_ROOTS excluding only unstable tests.
SANITY_SUBSET := $(TEST_TOOL_ROOTS) $(TEST_ROOTS)


##############################################################
#
# Test recipes
#
##############################################################

# This section contains recipes for tests other than the default.
# See makefile.default.rules for the default test rules.
# All tests in this section should adhere to the naming convention: <testname>.test

inscount_tls.test: $(OBJDIR)inscount_tls$(PINTOOL_SUFFIX) $(THREAD_APP)
    $(PIN) -t $(OBJDIR)inscount_tls$(PINTOOL_SUFFIX) -- $(THREAD_APP) > $(OBJDIR)inscount_tls.out 2>&1
    $(RM) $(OBJDIR)inscount_tls.out
    
replacesigprobed.test: $(OBJDIR)replacesigprobed$(PINTOOL_SUFFIX) $(TESTAPP)
    $(PIN) -t $(OBJDIR)replacesigprobed$(PINTOOL_SUFFIX) \
      -- $(TESTAPP) makefile $(OBJDIR)replacesigprobed.makefile.copy > $(OBJDIR)replacesigprobed.out
    $(DIFF) makefile $(OBJDIR)replacesigprobed.makefile.copy
    $(EGREP) "NewMalloc|Skip replacing" $(OBJDIR)replacesigprobed.out
    $(RM) $(OBJDIR)replacesigprobed.makefile.copy $(OBJDIR)replacesigprobed.out

malloc_mt.test: $(OBJDIR)malloc_mt$(PINTOOL_SUFFIX) $(THREAD_APP)
    $(PIN) -t $(OBJDIR)malloc_mt$(PINTOOL_SUFFIX) -- $(THREAD_APP) > $(OBJDIR)malloc_mt.out 2>&1
    $(RM) $(OBJDIR)malloc_mt.out

buffer_linux.test: $(OBJDIR)buffer_linux$(PINTOOL_SUFFIX) $(THREAD_APP)
    $(PIN) -t $(OBJDIR)buffer_linux$(PINTOOL_SUFFIX) -- $(THREAD_APP) > $(OBJDIR)buffer_linux.out 2>&1
    $(RM) $(OBJDIR)buffer_linux.out

buffer_windows.test: $(OBJDIR)buffer_windows$(PINTOOL_SUFFIX) $(THREAD_APP)
    $(PIN) -t $(OBJDIR)buffer_windows$(PINTOOL_SUFFIX) -emit 0 \
      -- $(THREAD_APP) > $(OBJDIR)buffer_windows.out 2>&1
    $(RM) $(OBJDIR)buffer_windows.out

invocation.test: $(OBJDIR)invocation$(PINTOOL_SUFFIX) $(OBJDIR)little_malloc$(EXE_SUFFIX)
    $(PIN) -t $(OBJDIR)invocation$(PINTOOL_SUFFIX) -- $(OBJDIR)little_malloc$(EXE_SUFFIX) > $(OBJDIR)invocation.out 2>&1
    $(RM) $(OBJDIR)invocation.out

# This tool is tested in "Debugger/makefile". However, leave this line because it is referenced in the user manual.
# The user may invoke make stack-debugger.test to build the tool and app shown in the manual.
# There is an intentional "empty" line which contains a tab character so this "test" will have an empty recipe.
stack-debugger.test: $(OBJDIR)stack-debugger$(PINTOOL_SUFFIX) $(OBJDIR)fibonacci$(EXE_SUFFIX)
    

# stand alone pin tool
statica.test: $(OBJDIR)statica$(SATOOL_SUFFIX)
    $(SET_DLL_PATH) $(OBJDIR)statica$(SATOOL_SUFFIX) -i $(OBJDIR)statica$(SATOOL_SUFFIX) > $(OBJDIR)statica.dmp
    $(RM) $(OBJDIR)statica.dmp

nonstatica.test: $(OBJDIR)nonstatica$(PINTOOL_SUFFIX) $(TESTAPP)
    $(PIN) -t $(OBJDIR)nonstatica$(PINTOOL_SUFFIX) \
      -- $(TESTAPP) makefile $(OBJDIR)nonstatica.makefile.copy > $(OBJDIR)nonstatica.dmp
    $(DIFF) makefile $(OBJDIR)nonstatica.makefile.copy
    $(RM) $(OBJDIR)nonstatica.makefile.copy $(OBJDIR)nonstatica.dmp

emudiv.test: $(OBJDIR)emudiv$(PINTOOL_SUFFIX) $(OBJDIR)divide_by_zero$(EXE_SUFFIX)
    $(PIN) -t $(OBJDIR)emudiv$(PINTOOL_SUFFIX) -- $(OBJDIR)divide_by_zero$(EXE_SUFFIX) > $(OBJDIR)emudiv.out 2>&1
    $(QGREP) "Caught divide by zero exception" $(OBJDIR)emudiv.out
    $(RM) $(OBJDIR)emudiv.out

fork_jit_tool.test: $(OBJDIR)fork_jit_tool$(PINTOOL_SUFFIX) $(OBJDIR)fork_app$(EXE_SUFFIX)
    $(PIN) -t $(OBJDIR)fork_jit_tool$(PINTOOL_SUFFIX) -- $(OBJDIR)fork_app$(EXE_SUFFIX)

follow_child_tool.test: $(OBJDIR)follow_child_tool$(PINTOOL_SUFFIX) $(OBJDIR)follow_child_app1$(EXE_SUFFIX) $(OBJDIR)follow_child_app2$(EXE_SUFFIX)
    $(PIN) -follow_execv 1 -t $(OBJDIR)follow_child_tool$(PINTOOL_SUFFIX) \
      -- $(OBJDIR)follow_child_app1$(EXE_SUFFIX) $(OBJDIR)follow_child_app2$(EXE_SUFFIX)

dumpargv.test: $(OBJDIR)dumpargv$(PINTOOL_SUFFIX) $(THREAD_APP)
    $(PIN) -error_file '\\isamba\nfs\site\ptl\bistro\log' -t $(OBJDIR)dumpargv$(PINTOOL_SUFFIX) \
      -- $(THREAD_APP) > $(OBJDIR)dumpargv.out 2>&1
    $(RM) $(OBJDIR)dumpargv.out

# Testing -prefer_parse_macho_from_mem 0 with this chosen test
prefer_parse_image_from_file.test: $(OBJDIR)imageload$(PINTOOL_SUFFIX) $(TESTAPP)
    $(PIN) -t $(OBJDIR)imageload$(PINTOOL_SUFFIX) -prefer_parse_macho_from_mem 0 -o $(OBJDIR)prefer_parse_image_from_file_tool.log \
      -- $(TESTAPP) makefile $(OBJDIR)prefer_parse_image_from_file.makefile.copy > $(OBJDIR)prefer_parse_image_from_file.out
    $(RM) $(OBJDIR)prefer_parse_image_from_file.makefile.copy $(OBJDIR)prefer_parse_image_from_file_tool.log \
          $(OBJDIR)prefer_parse_image_from_file.out

##############################################################
#
# Build rules
#
##############################################################

# This section contains the build rules for all binaries that have special build rules.
# See makefile.default.rules for the default build rules.

###### Special applications' build rules ######

$(OBJDIR)divide_by_zero$(EXE_SUFFIX): divide_by_zero_$(OS_TYPE).c
    $(APP_CC) $(APP_CXXFLAGS_NOOPT) $(COMP_EXE)$@ $< $(APP_LDFLAGS_NOOPT) $(APP_LIBS)


makefile.default.rules:
#
# Copyright (C) 2012-2022 Intel Corporation.
# SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
#

##############################################################
#
# This file contains the following:
# 1. All the common make targets which depend on the variables defined
#    in the per-directory makefile.rules files. The independent targets
#    are defined in makefile.config in this directory.
# 2. Default rules for building pintools and test applications.
# 3. Default test recipes.
#
##############################################################


##############################################################
#
# make targets
#
##############################################################

###### Finalize definitions - add prefixes and suffixes ######

SERIAL := $(SERIAL_SUBSET:%=%.wrap)
TESTS := $(TEST_TOOL_ROOTS:%=%.wrap) $(TEST_ROOTS:%=%.wrap)
TESTS := $(filter-out $(SERIAL), $(TESTS))
SANITY := $(SANITY_SUBSET:%=%.wrap)
SANITY := $(filter-out $(SERIAL), $(SANITY))
TOOLS := $(TEST_TOOL_ROOTS:%=$(OBJDIR)%$(PINTOOL_SUFFIX)) $(TOOL_ROOTS:%=$(OBJDIR)%$(PINTOOL_SUFFIX))
SA_TOOLS := $(SA_TOOL_ROOTS:%=$(OBJDIR)%$(SATOOL_SUFFIX))
APPS := $(APP_ROOTS:%=$(OBJDIR)%$(EXE_SUFFIX))
OBJECTS := $(OBJECT_ROOTS:%=$(OBJDIR)%$(OBJ_SUFFIX))
DLLS := $(DLL_ROOTS:%=$(OBJDIR)$(DLL_PREFIX)%$(DLL_SUFFIX))
LIBS := $(LIB_ROOTS:%=$(OBJDIR)%$(LIB_SUFFIX))

###### Create the output directory ######

# Create the output directory.
dir: $(OBJDIR)

print_filtered_tests:
    -@$(PYTHON) $(TOOLS_ROOT)/Utils/printFilteredTests.py --unfiltered_tests "$(RUNNABLE_TESTS)" --tests "$(TESTS) $(SERIAL)"

print_filtered_sanity_tests:
    -@$(PYTHON) $(TOOLS_ROOT)/Utils/printFilteredTests.py --unfiltered_tests "$(RUNNABLE_TESTS)" --tests "$(SANITY) $(SERIAL)"

obj-%:
    mkdir -p $@

# Add the output directory as an order-only dependency to all the binaries and tests.
# Order-only dependencies are all the dependencies that follow the "|" character.
# These dependencies do not mandate rebuilding the target if the dependency changed,
# only that the dependended-on file exists.
# In this case, we require that $(OBJDIR) exist, but we don't care if it has changed.
$(TEST_TOOL_ROOTS:%=%.test) $(TEST_ROOTS:%=%.test): %: | dir
$(TESTS) $(SANITY) $(SERAIL): %: | dir
$(TOOLS) $(TOOLS:%$(PINTOOL_SUFFIX)=%$(OBJ_SUFFIX)) $(SA_TOOLS) $(SA_TOOLS:%$(SATOOL_SUFFIX)=%$(OBJ_SUFFIX)): %: | dir
$(APPS) $(OBJECTS) $(DLLS) $(LIBS): %: | dir

###### Build ######

# Build the tools.
tools: dir $(TOOLS) $(SA_TOOLS)

# Build the applications.
apps: dir $(APPS)

# Build the additional object files.
objects: dir $(OBJECTS)

# Build the additional dlls.
dlls: dir $(DLLS)

# Build the static libraries.
libs: dir $(LIBS)

# Build the program which checks the hardware for avx support.
avxcheck: $(CHECKAVX)

# Build the program which checks the hardware for avx2 support.
avx2check: $(CHECKAVX2)

# Build the program which checks the hardware for tsx support.
tsxcheck: $(CHECKTSX)

# Build the program which checks the hardware for avx512f support.
avx512fcheck: $(CHECKAVX512F)

# Build the program which checks the hardware and OS for amx support.
amxcheck: $(CHECKAMX)

# Build the program which checks the hardware and OS for amx support.
movdir64bcheck: $(CHECKMOVDIR64B)

###### Install ######

# Build all and run a predefined installer where applicable.
install: all
    $(INSTALLER) $(INSTALL_FLAGS)
    @echo install complete!

###### Test ######

# Run all tests.
test: print_filtered_tests $(TESTS)

# Run the "short" sanity list. 
sanity: print_filtered_sanity_tests $(SANITY)

# Run the "Serial" list. 
serial: $(SERIAL)

summary:
    $(TOOLS_ROOT)/Utils/testsummary

###### Cleanup ######

# Remove any files that were created by the make process.
clean:
    -rm -rf $(OBJDIR) *.out* *.log* *.xml *.makefile.copy *.core core.*

clean-remote:
    -$(INSTALLER) $(INSTALL_FLAGS) --clean

###### Build the common components - for internal use ###### 

$(TESTAPP):
    $(MAKE) -C $(TOOLS_ROOT)/Utils dir $(OBJDIR)cp-pin$(EXE_SUFFIX)

$(HELLO_APP):
    $(MAKE) -C $(TOOLS_ROOT)/Utils dir $(OBJDIR)hello$(EXE_SUFFIX)

$(HELLO_APP_DWARF4):
    $(MAKE) -C $(TOOLS_ROOT)/Utils dir $(OBJDIR)hello_dwarf4$(EXE_SUFFIX)

$(DISABLE_ASLR):
    $(MAKE) -C $(TOOLS_ROOT)/Utils dir $(OBJDIR)disable-aslr$(EXE_SUFFIX)

$(ATTACH_LAUNCHER):
    $(MAKE) -C $(TOOLS_ROOT)/Utils dir $(OBJDIR)attachLauncher$(EXE_SUFFIX)

$(THREAD_APP):
    $(MAKE) -C $(TOOLS_ROOT)/Utils dir $(OBJDIR)thread_app$(EXE_SUFFIX)

$(INSCOUNT_TOOL):
    $(MAKE) -C $(TOOLS_ROOT)/ManualExamples dir $(OBJDIR)inscount0$(PINTOOL_SUFFIX)

$(CHECKAVX):
    $(MAKE) -C $(TOOLS_ROOT)/Utils dir $(OBJDIR)avx_check$(EXE_SUFFIX)

$(CHECKAVX2):
    $(MAKE) -C $(TOOLS_ROOT)/Utils dir $(OBJDIR)avx2_check$(EXE_SUFFIX)

$(CHECKAMX):
    $(MAKE) -C $(TOOLS_ROOT)/Utils dir $(OBJDIR)amx_check$(EXE_SUFFIX)

$(CHECKMOVDIR64B):
    $(MAKE) -C $(TOOLS_ROOT)/Utils dir $(OBJDIR)movdir64b_check$(EXE_SUFFIX)

$(CHECKTSX):
    $(MAKE) -C $(TOOLS_ROOT)/Utils dir $(OBJDIR)tsx_check$(EXE_SUFFIX)

$(CHECKAVX512F):
    $(MAKE) -C $(TOOLS_ROOT)/Utils dir $(OBJDIR)avx512f_check$(EXE_SUFFIX)

$(THREADLIB):
    $(MAKE) -C $(TOOLS_ROOT)/Utils dir $(OBJDIR)threadlib$(OBJ_SUFFIX)
  
$(RUNNABLE):
    $(MAKE) -C $(TOOLS_ROOT)/Utils dir $(OBJDIR)runnable$(OBJ_SUFFIX)
  
$(THREADPOOL):
    $(MAKE) -C $(TOOLS_ROOT)/Utils dir $(OBJDIR)thread_pool$(OBJ_SUFFIX)
  
$(SYSMEMORY):
    $(MAKE) -C $(TOOLS_ROOT)/Utils dir $(OBJDIR)sys_memory$(OBJ_SUFFIX)

$(REGVALLIB):
    $(MAKE) -C $(TOOLS_ROOT)/Utils dir $(OBJDIR)regvallib$(LIB_SUFFIX)

$(CONTROLLERLIB):
    $(MAKE) -C $(TOOLS_ROOT)/InstLib dir $(OBJDIR)controller$(LIB_SUFFIX)

$(SUPPORTS_AVX_OBJ):
    $(MAKE) -C $(TOOLS_ROOT)/Utils dir $(OBJDIR)supports_avx$(OBJ_SUFFIX)

$(SUPPORTS_AVX2_OBJ):
    $(MAKE) -C $(TOOLS_ROOT)/Utils dir $(OBJDIR)supports_avx2$(OBJ_SUFFIX)

$(SUPPORTS_AVX512F_OBJ):
    $(MAKE) -C $(TOOLS_ROOT)/Utils dir $(OBJDIR)supports_avx512f$(OBJ_SUFFIX)

ifeq ($(TARGET),intel64)
$(SUPPORTS_AMX_OBJ):
    $(MAKE) -C $(TOOLS_ROOT)/Utils dir $(OBJDIR)supports_amx_intel64$(OBJ_SUFFIX)
endif

$(SET_XMM_SCRATCHES_OBJ):
    $(MAKE) -C $(TOOLS_ROOT)/Utils dir $(OBJDIR)set_xmm_scratches_asm$(OBJ_SUFFIX)

###### Automated testing utilities - for internal use ######

$(OBJDIR)%.tested:
    touch $@

#$(OBJDIR)%.failed:
#   touch $@

# Prevent these from being deleted if the test recipe fails.
.PRECIOUS: $(OBJDIR)%.tested $(OBJDIR)%.failed

# Don't delete the files generated in the Utils directory.
.PRECIOUS: $(TESTAPP) $(HELLO_APP) $(HELLO_APP_DWARF4) $(DISABLE_ASLR) $(ATTACH_LAUNCHER) $(THREAD_APP)
.PRECIOUS: $(CHECKAVX) $(CHECKAVX2) $(CHECKTSX) $(CHECKAVX512F) $(CHECKAMX)
.PRECIOUS: $(THREADLIB) $(SUPPORTS_AVX_OBJ) $(SUPPORTS_AVX2_OBJ) $(SUPPORTS_AVX512F_OBJ) $(SET_XMM_SCRATCHES_OBJ)
.PRECIOUS: $(RUNNABLE) $(THREADPOOL) $(SYSMEMORY)

# Accelerate the make process and prevent errors.
.PHONY: tools apps objects dlls libs avxcheck tsxcheck install test sanity serial summary clean %.test %.wrap

##############################################################
#
# Default build rules
#
##############################################################

###### Default build rules for tools ######

# Build the intermediate object file.
$(OBJDIR)%$(OBJ_SUFFIX): %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(TOOL_CXXFLAGS) $(COMP_OBJ)$@ $<

# Build the intermediate object file.
$(OBJDIR)%$(OBJ_SUFFIX): %.c
    $(CC) $(TOOL_CFLAGS) $(COMP_OBJ)$@ $<

# Build the tool as a dll (shared object).
$(OBJDIR)%$(PINTOOL_SUFFIX): $(OBJDIR)%$(OBJ_SUFFIX)
    $(LINKER) $(TOOL_LDFLAGS) $(LINK_EXE)$@ $< $(TOOL_LPATHS) $(TOOL_LIBS)

# Build the static analysis tools.
$(SA_TOOLS): %$(SATOOL_SUFFIX): %$(OBJ_SUFFIX)
    $(LINKER) $(SATOOL_LDFLAGS) $(LINK_EXE)$@ $^ $(SATOOL_LPATHS) $(SATOOL_LIBS)

# Don't delete the object files and dlls.
.PRECIOUS: $(OBJDIR)%$(OBJ_SUFFIX) $(OBJDIR)%$(PINTOOL_SUFFIX)

###### Default build rules for asm objects ######

# Source and target have the same name.
$(OBJDIR)%$(OBJ_SUFFIX): %$(ASM_SUFFIX)
    $(ASMBLR) $(ASM_FLAGS) $(COMP_OBJ)$@ $<

# Target name includes the string "_asm".
$(OBJDIR)%_asm$(OBJ_SUFFIX): %$(ASM_SUFFIX)
    $(ASMBLR) $(ASM_FLAGS) $(COMP_OBJ)$@ $<

# Several source versions depending on architecture.
$(OBJDIR)%$(OBJ_SUFFIX): %_$(TARGET)$(ASM_SUFFIX)
    $(ASMBLR) $(ASM_FLAGS) $(COMP_OBJ)$@ $<

# Same as above, but target name includes the string "_asm".
$(OBJDIR)%_asm$(OBJ_SUFFIX): %_$(TARGET)$(ASM_SUFFIX)
    $(ASMBLR) $(ASM_FLAGS) $(COMP_OBJ)$@ $<

# Several source versions depending on OS type.
$(OBJDIR)%$(OBJ_SUFFIX): %_$(OS_TYPE)$(ASM_SUFFIX)
    $(ASMBLR) $(ASM_FLAGS) $(COMP_OBJ)$@ $<

# Same as above, but target name includes the string "_asm".
$(OBJDIR)%_asm$(OBJ_SUFFIX): %_$(OS_TYPE)$(ASM_SUFFIX)
    $(ASMBLR) $(ASM_FLAGS) $(COMP_OBJ)$@ $<

# Several source versions depending on architecture and OS type.
$(OBJDIR)%$(OBJ_SUFFIX): %_$(TARGET)_$(OS_TYPE)$(ASM_SUFFIX)
    $(ASMBLR) $(ASM_FLAGS) $(COMP_OBJ)$@ $<

# Same as above, but target name includes the string "_asm".
$(OBJDIR)%_asm$(OBJ_SUFFIX): %_$(TARGET)_$(OS_TYPE)$(ASM_SUFFIX)
    $(ASMBLR) $(ASM_FLAGS) $(COMP_OBJ)$@ $<

###### Default build rules for applications ######

$(OBJDIR)%$(EXE_SUFFIX): %.cpp
    $(APP_CXX) $(APP_CXXFLAGS) $(COMP_EXE)$@ $< $(APP_LDFLAGS) $(APP_LIBS) $(CXX_LPATHS) $(CXX_LIBS)

$(OBJDIR)%$(EXE_SUFFIX): %.c
    $(APP_CC) $(APP_CXXFLAGS) $(COMP_EXE)$@ $< $(APP_LDFLAGS) $(APP_LIBS)


##############################################################
#
# Default test recipes
#
##############################################################

###### Default test rules ######

# This wrapper is used by the nightly/sanity/serail testing. No need to use it outside of this file.
# NOTE: makesure the test name is last parameter when using junit_test_wrap.py as TEST_PERFIX
#%.wrap: $(OBJDIR) $(OBJDIR)%.tested $(OBJDIR)%.failed
%.wrap: $(OBJDIR) $(OBJDIR)%.tested
    touch $(OBJDIR)$(@:.wrap=.failed)
    $(TEST_PREFIX) $(MAKE) $(MAKE_TESTFLAGS) $(@:.wrap=.test)   
    rm $(OBJDIR)$(@:.wrap=.failed)

# Not all tools produce output so the .out file might not be created. We don't want the test to fail in this case,
# so we ignore possible failures of the final rm command.
%.test: $(OBJDIR) $(OBJDIR)%$(PINTOOL_SUFFIX) $(TESTAPP)
    $(PIN) -t $(OBJDIR)$(@:.test=)$(PINTOOL_SUFFIX) -- $(TESTAPP) makefile $(OBJDIR)$(@:.test=.makefile.copy) \
      > $(OBJDIR)$(@:.test=.out) 2>&1
    $(CMP) makefile $(OBJDIR)$(@:.test=.makefile.copy)
    $(RM) $(OBJDIR)$(@:.test=.makefile.copy)
    -$(RM) $(OBJDIR)$(@:.test=.out)


I have also checked if the dll is present in the system. Moreover, compiling the c++ source without the pin.h lib from VS 2022 works.

Using Dependencies walker I saw that the ws2_32.dll is loaded withoud problem. So I'm thinking that when pin try to execute my custom pintool dll there are some problems. Any advice?
